# Production Standards to create Class Instances based on a string parameter in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I currently am using If else statement to determine which class instance to create but I think there is probably a better way to create these classes.

I have tried if, else statements, and case statement but i would like something more scalable than those types.

Also, I the names are not known until a for loop is run then creates the class and item currently using an if/else statement.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    SomeItem item;
    ISomeInterface sf;

    public SomeClass(SomeItem item)
    {
        this.item = item
    }

    public SomeItem UpdateItem()
    {
        string name = item.name;

        if (name == "a")
        {
            sf = new ClassA(item);
        }
        else if (name == "b")
        {
            sf = new ClassB(item);
        }
        else if (name == "c")
        {
            sf = new ClassC(item);
        }
        else
        {
            sf = new ClassD(item);
        }

        return sf.GetItem();
    }
}
```

Class works but I want to optimize as would be done in production standard code.

Comment: The *actual* question seems to be how to call a method from different instances based on a parameter. This has nothing to do with "production standards". There are countless ways you can simplify this, based on the actual requirements. You could clean this up with a simple `switch`. Or you could use a `Dictionary<string,Func<string,SomeItem>>` that matches names to function delegates that create an item based on a name. Or you can use a factory pattern implementation

Comment: "optimize"? Optimize for what? Time spent? Will you only have 4-5 classes? Or a dynamic number (ie. unknown until runtime) or do you know you will have many of them? Other than rewriting it to a switch or something, I'm not sure you can optimize *this particular case* any better.

Comment: BTW you probably don't need different *classes* to begin with. An ORM like EF could easily works with different entities withouth requiring hard-coded type switching. It does this by using function delegates/lambdas

Comment: Do you know which class you need beforehand? Or is this determined on the name? If you know the name do you know the type as well?

Comment: When i say production standards.. i mean what i've learned in my short time working on production code is that in a large production environment lead/sr developer pretty much hate case statements and rarely use if/else statements because usually there is a better way of doing things such as the mentioned ways (excluding switch and if/else)...      
By optimize i mean no doing if/else or switch statements because it is inefficient to make updates to these when scaling a service and it would be inefficient if there were 100s of classes to be initiallized and some may be changed or removed later

Comment: @Jaques There is a list of names that i know as i loop through a list and that name determines the type.

Comment: if there is a pattern connecting the string an the class name, you can use reflection to find a type based on its name and make an instance. If you want it to work fully automatically, you can create an interface with a public member holding the string value and then find all classes implementing it, choose the correct one and create an instance. Reflecion would a way to go in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (name)
{
    case "a":
        sf = new ClassA(item);
        break;
    case "b":
        sf = new ClassB(item);
        break;
    case "c":
        sf = new ClassC(item);
        break;
    default:
        sf = new ClassD(item);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches to consider here

**Use a Factory**

You can have a separate Factory class, that just has the job to create a new instance based on whatever parameters you have to decide. In your example its name, but it can be more than that.

```
public class ObjectFactory
{
    public BaseType Instance(string name)
    {
        switch(name)
        {
            case "A":
                return A();
            case "B":
                return B()
        }
    }
}
```

**Use Dependency Injection**

You can use dependency injection. Register all your classes and specify the key. The key for the type will be the name by which you are deciding the instance. Then dynamically inject your class instance based on the name. All logic of creating an instance and returning it back will be handled by the DI framework. You can look up [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md)

**Use Different factory classes for all types**
You can make that dynamic and move the logic of matching the type inside the type itself if you want.

```
    var instances = new Base[]
    {
        new A(),
        new B()
    };

    foreach(var instance in instances)
    {
        if(instance.IsMatch(name))
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract bool IsMatch(string name);
}

public class A : Base
{
    public override bool IsMatch(string name)
    {
        return name.ToUpper() == "A";
    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public override bool IsMatch(string name)
    {
        return name.ToUpper() == "B";
    }
}
```